# add css when slide is clicked in swiperjs angular

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js, ngx-swiper-wrapper

I have multiple slides and when 1 is selected I want to add border color to it and when the other slide is selected, the border color is then added to the new slide and removed from the other.

```
public desktopConfig: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 3.5,
    navigation: false,
    breakpoints: {
      0: {
        allowTouchMove: true
      },
      768: {
        allowTouchMove: false
      }
    }
```

I don't want to use jquery, and add the border color when one is selected and remove from the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking too much, I just made a div inside swiper tag and gave a condition to add a class to it onselect.

```
<swiper [config]="desktopConfig" class="mySwiper">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let param of data">
            <ng-template swiperSlide>
                <div (click)="selectB(param)"
                    [class.active]="isSelected">
                    <img [src]="">
                    <div>
                        {{param.title}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
    </swiper>
```